# How do I manually trigger an event with PyGTK event handler?

Tags: python, events, triggers, pygtk

after connecting an event to a function, I would like a way to trigger the event manually (without the event actually happening). I'm looking for something like jQuery's .trigger() function.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`emit` method](http://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/class-gobject.html#method-gobject--emit) on the widget, e.g. `button.emit("clicked")`.